# Thinkpad T540p, 16.04 LTS, microphone doesn't work at all

Tags: 16.04, thinkpad, microphone

I've got a huge issue with my build in microphone of my Lenovo T540p notebook. I am new to Ubuntu and using the 16.04 LTS.

I already read many threads about this and tried to solve it with ALSA mixer and pavucontrol. Nothing worked. In pavucontrol it seems that my micro doesn't detect any sound.

Thanks in advance!